# PHP calculate date interval from 0/0/0 00:00:00

Tags: php, date, datetime, strtotime, duration

I need to calculate a duration and make it human readable.
e.g. I have a string: "2 days 4 hours". I need my code to calculate the duration of that string as a timestamp and to make it human readable.

My problem is that if I add the timestamp to `0`, it starts from 1/1/1970, but I need it to just calculate the duration.

I tried to subtract 1/1/1970 01:01:00 to `0` but when calculating it returns a no-sense result.

Comment: We can't help you if you don't post the code you've written

Comment: If a time is zero then what is the interval you're trying to measure? You need to clarify your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you would like to transform something like:

```
$dateString = "2 days 4 hours";
```

to timestamp?

If that is the case, and you know there will always be days/hours you could do something like:

```
$dateString = "2 days 4 hours";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $dateString , $numbersOnly);
$partialTimeStamp= (($numbersOnly[0][0]*24)+$numbersOnly[0][1])*3600;
print_r($partialTimeStamp); // will print 187200
```

With this you will have a numbers of seconds. If for example you also have minutes in your string you would do:

```
$dateString = "2 days 4 hours 15 minutes";
preg_match_all('!\d+!', $dateString , $numbersOnly);
$partialTimeStamp= (($numbersOnly[0][0]*24)+$numbersOnly[0][1])*3600 + $numbersOnly[0][2]*60;
print_r($partialTimeStamp); // will print 188100
```

And with this partial timestamp, you can than calculate next timestamp like:

```
$nextTimeStamp = time () + $partialTimeStamp;
print_r($nextTimeStamp);
```

EDIT: Missed the "back to human readable" part..
For this, you would do something like:

```
$days = floor($partialTimeStamp/ 86400);
$partialTimeStamp = $partialTimeStamp - $days*86400;
$hours = floor($partialTimeStamp/ 3600);
$min = floor($partialTimeStamp/ 60 % 60);
```

And than just this:

```
print_r($days." days ".$hours." hours ".$min. " minutes");// will output 2 days 4 hours 15 minutes
```

I hope this helps.

BR

Comment: It has been very helpful, even if it wasn't the exact solution. Thank you very much.